# laravel how to get user conversation list

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm developing a message chat system,
but I have a problem with making a list of chat rooms,
currently I have three tables

```
users
id | name      | avastar     
1  | name1     | /img/avatar/1.jpg          
2  | name2     | /img/avatar/2.jpg        
3  | name3     | /img/avatar/3.jpg           
         
user_messages
id | message_id | sender_id   | receiver_id | created_at
1  | 1          | 1           | 3           |  2022-12-13 19:34:11
2  | 2          | 3           | 1           |  2022-12-13 19:35:00
3  | 3          | 1           | 2           |  2022-12-14 16:28:00
4  | 4          | 1           | 2           |  2022-12-15 09:39:00
5  | 5          | 2           | 3           |  2022-12-15 10:01:00

messages
id | message 
1  | hello        
2  | hello    
3  | hello       
4  | how are you         
5  | hi
```

user1 chat list displays a message with user2 and user3
This message requires user2 and user3 's name and avatar
last message content and  send time

How to query?

```
class UserMessage extends Model
{
    public function message(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Message::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Message extends Model
{
    public function user_messages(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserMessage::class);
    }

    public  function  users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_messages', 'message_id', 'sender_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

I want the list of this page to display the content of the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebFxZ.jpg)

zohrehda's answer is awesome
share the following code it works.

```
 $messages=UserMessage::
            where('receiver_id',$user_id)
            ->orWhere('sender_id',$user_id)
            ->LeftJoin('messages','user_messages.message_id','messages.id')
            ->select('user_messages.*','messages.message')
            ->get();
        $chat_list=[] ;
        foreach($messages as $message){
            if($message->receiver_id !=$user_id)
            {
                $chat_list[$message->receiver_id][]=$message ;

            }elseif($message->sender_id !=$user_id){

                $chat_list[$message->sender_id][]=$message ;

            }

        }
        $array=[] ;
        foreach($chat_list as $user_id=>$messages)
        {
            $user=User::find($user_id) ;
            $array[]=[
                'user_name'=> $user->name ,
                'user_avatar'=>$user->avatar ,
                'last_message' =>last($messages)->message,
                'created_at'=>last($messages)->created_at
            ];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to gather messages related to the user that means messages which receiver or sender of that is the current user.

then loop in this messages and create a chat_list array that the key
is the user id and the value is all messages that the current user and specified user had conversation.

```
$messages=Message::where('receiver_id',$user->id)->orWhere('sender_id',$user->id)->get();
$chat_list=[] ;
foreach($messages as $message){
   if($message->receiver_id !=$user->id)
   { 
    $chat_list[$message->receiver_id][]=$message ;
    
   }elseif($message->sender_id !=$user->id){
   
    $chat_list[$message->sender_id][]=$message ;

  }
 
}
$array=[] ;
foreach($chat_list as $user_id=>$messages)
{
   $user=User::find($user_id) ;
   $array[]=[
  
       'user_name'=> $user->name ,
       'user_avatar'=>$user->avatar ,
       'last_message' =>last($messages)->message->message ,
       'created_at'=> last($messages)->created_at
 
   ];
}
```

remmember `$chat_list` is a the list of user chat. the key is user contact and the value is all their conversation.
`$array` variable is exact what use need

I hope this work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I want the list of this page to display the content of the image below
here is link https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebFxZ.jpg

Comment: I updated my answer . I described two ways

Comment: Sorry to bother you. This is not work.
Can you edit the code according to my example table? Thanks

Comment: is there error? I coded according to your table. what is the bug?

Comment: I removed second way. it's not working. but the first one is correct and I tested it

Comment: The second way will have duplicate data. I change the first method now, I get the error Call to a member function last() on array.
I updated my current code above.

Comment: use `last($messages)->message->message` and for the next line

Comment: May I ask if I add seen_status column in the user_message table to count how many messages the user has not seen?
when seen_status=0 user has not seen

Comment: use can add this element to $array variable  `'unread_count'=> collect(messages)->where('receiver_id',$auth_user->id)->where('seen_status',0)->count() `